# How one legally can justify distance learning for on campus programs?

Tags: online-learning, online-degree, accreditation

A few years ago we wanted to open a new program that will be based on distance learning,  however, getting accredited for having a master degree program that is based on distance learning and not on campus is literally a bureaucratic nightmare.
First, no one allowed us to use Zoom, Microsoft Teams or other currently popular distance learning tools, second it should be some sort of  "Moodle" program with clear guidelines for each week. Third everything needs to be under guidelines of the Distance Education Accrediting Commission, in current COVID19 teaching organizational crisis we don't follow those guidelines at all.
I wonder what are legal repercussions for doing distance learning when you are not accredited to do one. Can our students with disability complain since when they needed this option we couldn't provide to them since our excuse was that we weren't ready or accredited to do so? And last but not least, can we legally organize accredited on-campus program but perform it online or using distance learning completely?

Comment: So many questions and a few years ago you did not have the unique conditions as now.

Comment: These questions should be directed to your institutional council (staff lawyer).

Comment: it is actually only one question @SolarMike

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist guidelines for getting accredited in a program that is based on distance learning is pretty straightforward

Comment: “I wonder what the legal repercussions” then “can our students with disability complain” then can we legally organize accredited on-campus ...”. I think I count 3 just there, but you only 1...

Comment: no it is only one regarding legal consequences @SolarMike

Comment: Well, my comment was my opinion, what happens with the voting will clarify.

Comment: Trying to use the current (temporary, for some value of temporary) situation to justify some other, permanent, distance class delivery system is doomed to failure. The universities have been shut by government order. I suppose they _could_ have just annulled this semester, but have chosen to try and do something, anything, to get students through this time. I suppose if we start having annual pandemics of novel viruses you might get more traction.

Comment: @JonCuster so they do because of  convenience

Comment: No, this isn’t ‘convenience’ - good grief. Hard to tell just where that comes from, but if you can’t recognize that the current situation is unique in our lifetime, and hopefully a one-off thing, well... Now, whether this ultimately increases demand for official distance learning options is a different question.

Comment: @JonCuster you should put that in answer. I understand now.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** this answer is somewhat specific to the context of the COVID-19 health crisis and about legal justifications for various exceptional teaching strategies being adopted by many universities all over the world these days. It’s not clear if that’s what you meant to ask about exactly. If it’s not, please clarify.

---

The COVID-19 situation and the way universities are responding to it is an illustration of the adage that “it is easier to ask for forgiveness than for permission”. Basically the situation is so unprecedented that universities are doing whatever they can to stay operational, and leaving legal questions for later. My guess is that these will all be addressed by governments, legislatures, and regulatory bodies at a later time when the people in charge emerge out of panic mode and have time for dealing with such issues.

At the same time, the question of legality is indeed significant, and people are in fact paying attention. For example, in the US, I have heard that the visas of many foreign students explicitly forbid “online learning”. As a result, I have also heard (this is basically gossip and I can’t confirm it or cite a reference) that some institutions are referring to their current mode of operation as “remote learning” in a euphemistic attempt to pretend that that’s conceptually different from “online learning”. Silly? Perhaps, but that’s the kind of advice lawyers are giving apparently. Similar fig-leaf, [CYA](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cya)-style advice is being given about protecting your Zoom class meeting with a password to avoid being accused of compromising your students’ privacy. Does that mean using Zoom is technically legal in the sense of being fully [FERPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_Educational_Rights_and_Privacy_Act)-compliant? Who knows - probably not. But at least we make an effort to minimize whatever legal issues we have time to think about and energy to do something about.

But the short answer is, in the academic context as well as other contexts having to do with civil liberties, restrictions on people’s movements and many other aspects of our daily lives that are being disrupted, the law is lagging far behind. People in charge will do whatever they need to do without asking for permission, and ask for forgiveness later if they have to (they probably won’t).

Comment: A very interesting and important answer. is it ethical and legal to open online program, but to register it as on campus in current situation?

Comment: @SSimon Are you asking if it would be ethical to take advantage of the current crisis to open an online program you couldn't before because of bureaucratic problems? Of course not.

Comment: @SSimon are you seriously asking if it’s ethical and legal to commit fraud “in current situation”? Please tell me I’m missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the bureaucratic jungle can be skirted: Offer an on-campus program, deliver material digitally, and make a room available for screenings of that material. Deliver office hours, tutorials, etc. digitally too, allowing students to be in the room, should they choose. You *are* offering an on-campus program. You're also doing an excellent job of catering for students that can't make class, e.g., they're sick, their kid is sick, their car broke down, ... As it turns out, your program is also excellent for distance learning.

Perhaps you'd fall foul under inspection, then you're reliant on begging for forgiveness, as Dan [mentioned](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/147468/22768). Get your head of department on-board, get a legal opinion.

> can we legally organize accredited on-campus program but perform it online or using distance learning completely?

That's a legal question, INAL, but perhaps an accredited on-campus program can be delivered without any students present... And, if that happens, it'd make economic sense to drop the screening room, students can use existing computer facilities (typically paid from someone else's budget).

Comment: yes, but is it legal?

Comment: @SSimon INAL and this site is inappropriate for such questions